# Unable To Render Blender Clothing Animation

Tags: rendering, animation, cloth-simulation

I see a purple screen when I render the animation of my garment instead of the actual garment.
How do I resolve this?

Thank you

[image: The rendered result of the garment.]

Comment: Could you share you .blend file so the problem would be easier to solve? Or maybe other pictures of your scene? At the moment it seems like your camera is too close to your garment but it could be something else. At the moment we don't have much info to work with.

Comment: Has it been baked?